# in posting in spring boot, how to separate the value from form submitted and the one from url if both uses same name/parameter attribute?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, post, form-data

so i have a form in with inputs id and nickname

i have a method in controller that accepts post:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public String post(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, Map<String, String> queryParameters, @Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "form") Person form, BindingResult bRes) {}
```

Person class:

```
@lombok.Data
public abstract class Person {
    @NotNull
    protected Long id;
    @NotBlank
    protected String nickname;
}
```

my problem is when the form action is changed to '/test?nickname=John' and in the input has value of Doe, the nickname of Person becomes 'John,Doe'

is there a way to separate the 2 or just get the value in the form only

doing request.getParameter("nickname") returns the url parameter version or 'John' in this case.
doing request.getParameterValues("nickname") returns all or john and doe in this case.

normally a workaround is get the last value of request.getParameterValues("nickname"):

```
String[] tempNicknames = request.getParameterValues("nickname");
String postNickname = tempNicknames[tempNicknames.length-1];
```

but if the nickname converted to lists of strings the workaround will not work anymore